# How to calculate the orientation of an object moving along a hermite curve

Tags: math, matrix, rotation, curve, quaternions

I struggle with the orientation of an object I am moving along a hermite curve.
I figured out how to move it at constant speed at also have the tangent of my curve, which would be the forward vector of the moving object. My problem is: How do I know the up and right vector? The easiest way would be to start at a given rotation and then step through the curve always taking the last rotation as a reference for the next one, like in this reference:

[Camera movement along a spline](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Efp/courses/graphics/asst5/cameraMovement.pdf)pdf

But this would result in an uncontrollable rotation at the end of the spline. What I am trying to do is to create an algorithm which gives you the correct orientation at any point of the curve, without stepping through it. Ideally it would use the orientation of the two controlpoints for the current segment as a reference.

I thought of using some kind of pre-calculated data, which is created from the two orientations of the controlpoints and the current curve segments form, but didn't manage to come up with a solution.

I would be happy to get any answers or just ideas how to approach this problem.

Comment: Don't you want to use the Frenet trihedron ? An alternative approach could be to specify a second curve "parallel" to the first, such that the vector from the camera to the second curve, together with the tangent vector, defines the reference horizon plane of the camera (and by Gram-Schmidt the complete reference frame).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK i came up with a solution using frenet frames. I define an orientation for each of my control points, then i calculate a number of points along the spline for each segment. Each points orientation is then calculated using the previous points orientation. The orientatin of the first point equals the orientation of the control point. 
[Here](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~fp/courses/graphics/asst5/cameraMovement.pdf) is a very nice description of the procedure.
After calculating each points orientation, you can interpolate them so the last points orientation matches the orientation of the next controlpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Let `C(t)` be the camera trajectory, with tangent vector `T(t)`. The tangent vector controls the pitch and the yaw. What you are missing is roll control.

Define an auxiliary trajectory `D(t)` that "parallels" `C(t)` and use the vector `CD(t)`. The up vector is given by `U(t)=T(t) /\ CD(t)` (normalized), and the right vector by `U(t) /\ T(t)` (normalized).

Comment: The Frenet trihendron seems to be what i am looking for, now i just have to understand how it works. Thanks for the advice. If i define a second curve, i run into issus with the offset, if its a global offset like [0,1,0] i would run into issues with parts of the curve facing directly upwards or simmilar with other offsets.

Comment: I didn't say that the offset must be constant. Using an extra curve gives you more flexibility to control camera movement and leave the osculating plane. Also consider that on a straightline the Frenet trihedron is undefined.